# How to create a new object through code

Tags: java

for a class project, we have to make a family in Java. So our person class looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    boolean isMale;
    int age;

    //Make new person with age set to 0
    public Person(String firstName, String middleName, boolean isMale)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName.trim().toUpperCase();
        this.middleName = middleName.trim().toUpperCase();
        this.isMale = isMale;
        this.age = 0;
    }
}
```

We're trying to have another class call upon this and make a new `Person` based of inputs.

```
public class Family
{
    String surname;
    Person husband;
    Person wife;
    Person child

    //////
    //The following is supposed to make a new Person() with the following variables set. However, I don't know how to do this.
    //////

    public void haveChild(String firstName, String middleName, boolean isMale)
    {
        Person baby;
        System.out.println(firstName.trim().toUpperCase() + " is born."); //Prints Child's name
        this.child = child; //Set's the created Person() object as variable Child, or at least that's what this is intended to do.
    }
}
```

So that's what I have so far. I just can't seem to figure out what I need to do next. I've attempted to use `new Person();` and other variations, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `new Person()` is the right idea. You should show us what you did try and any error messages or incorrect behavior that happened.

Comment: What do you want the program to do? do you want to set the person objects inside your family class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void haveChild(String firstName, String middleName, boolean isMale)
{
    System.out.println(firstName.trim().toUpperCase() + " is born."); //Prints Child's name
    this.child = new Person(firstName, middleName, isMale); //Set's the created Person() object as variable Child, or at least that's what this is intended to do.
}
```

Comment: It's weird, I tried that before and it didn't work, I guess I must have missed something.

Comment: Classes can be confusing for someone just learning to code. Just always make sure you fill in all parameters as well as make sure your filling them with the right variable type.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are searching for, but hopefully this can help in some way:

```
public class Family
{
    String surname;
    Person husband;
    Person wife;
    Person child

public void setHusband(String firstname, String middlename, boolean isMale, int age){
    //Initialize the husband class
    this.husband = new Person(firstname, middlename, isMale, age);
}

 public void setWife(String firstname, String middlename, boolean isMale, int age){
    //Initialize the wife person class
    this.wife = new Person(firstname, middlename, isMale, age);
}

public void haveChild(String firstName, String middleName, boolean isMale)
{
    System.out.println(firstName.trim().toUpperCase() + " is born."); //Prints Child's name
    this.child = new Person(firstname, middlename, isMale, age);
}
}
```

Then you can then create a method for getting the details of each person class inside your family class #Getters and Setters!

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for going above and beyond. Luckily we already had the Husband and Wife taken care of by creating them through the Person Class, and then assigning them when making the Family object. But again, thank you very much.